# Check if a list of divs are overlaping a static one when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a list of posts and a logo at the bottom of the page. The title of the posts is in the far left as well as the logo and they overlap at certain positions. I need to set a 0.25 opacity on the logo image only if the text from .cat-date is above the .logo.

I've tried getting the position from bottom for each element, but the logo stays with 0.25 opacity every time.

Thanks!

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.cat-date').each(function(){
        var bottom = $(this).position().top+$(this).outerHeight(true);//distance from bottom
        if (bottom < 210){
            $(".logo").css("opacity","0.25");
        }
    console.log(bottom)
  })
});
```

```css
.cat-date{
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  color:blue;
  margin-bottom:150px;
  z-index:9999;
  position:relative;
}
.logo{
  height:50px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:red;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div> 
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: That is because you never change it back. You only set it to .25 but never back to 1

Comment: @putvande there are many elements on the page so bottom has multiple values. That's why I find it harder to go back to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var logoTop = $('.logo').offset().top;
    var logoBottom = logoTop + $('.logo').height();
    $('.cat-date').each(function(){
        var catTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var catBottom = catTop + $(this).height();
        if(catTop > logoTop && catTop < logoBottom || catBottom > logoTop && catBottom < logoBottom) {
            $('.logo').css('opacity', '0.25');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('.logo').css('opacity', '1');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.cat-date{//Just remove the `height` property from the `.cat-date` selector
  width:200px;
  color:blue;
  margin-bottom:150px;
  z-index:9999;
  position:relative;
}
.logo{
  height:50px;
  width:250px;
  background-color:red;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div> 
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="cat-date">lambada lambada</div>
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: awesome, your last edit did the trick. nice solution. cheers!